# Google Assistant shortcut to "Repeat after me" isn't responding

Tags: google-home, google-assistant

I am using a [Google Assistant shortcut](http://www.androidpolice.com/2017/10/07/google-assistant-shortcuts-can-make-home-say-anything/) to make my Google Home respond with a command.

Using the google Home app, under more settings, I created:

> When I say: "This is a test"
>
> Google Assistant should: "Repeat after me, This is not a test"

After saving, when I say "Hi Google, this is a test", nothing happens.

Even if I say to my Google Assistant directly, "Hi Google, repeat after me, ABC" nothing happens. Is "repeat after me" a working command?

I searched many pages: The most complete command list I have  found so far is [ok-google.io](http://ok-google.io/). This list does not contain "Repeat after me " command.

Comment: What shows up in your [history](https://androidkenya.com/2017/05/google-assistant-conversation-history/)? I wonder if your Assistant registered that you said "This is a test" and didn't respond, or whether it just didn't hear you right.

Comment: Where is history? in google home or assistant?

Comment: @SNash You probably want your Home history; instructions are [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/googlehome/comments/5b4qyz/can_you_see_a_history_of_questionscommands_in/). You should probably also merge your accounts if this is your question; please [see the help center](https://iot.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) for instructions.

Comment: update: even if I say to google assistance directly "Hi Google, Repeat after me , ABC " nothing happens. is repeat after me a working command?

Comment: "Repeat after me" is a valid command and should be working, according to [this article](http://www.androidpolice.com/2017/10/07/google-assistant-shortcuts-can-make-home-say-anything/). Have you tried other commands? Are they all working normally?